# Basic django2 web page

Tags: django, django-2.1

I'm trying to learn django(version 2.1), I thought of creating a webpage which has a text_field(to accept the path of a csv in a local machine) and and button to submit  the request. OR even a text field and a button, which prints the text entered in the text box in upper case and something like this. Youtube and other websites are filled with blogging apps, polling apps and some other complex stuff which i couldn't follow. I tried almost 30-40 different application from all over the internet, still didn't able to get the things right. Please please somebody guide me to create one of the above basic stuff else if you have any study material recommendations, will be greatly appreciated!

Please don't rush to mark it as a broad post, this might serve as learners guide for newbies like me.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get an idea. If you did not want a file picker you can just add a text field and retrieve the value from the text field like you would any other form value.

#### Template

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load extras %}
{% block content %}

    <div>

        <form action="." method="POST">
        {{ form }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

#### View

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PathForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['html-file-attribute-name']

        # Write the file to disk
        fout = open("path/to/save/file/to/%s" % uploaded_file.name, 'wb')
        for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
            fout.write(chunk)
        fout.close()
```

#### Form

```
class PathForm(forms.Form):
    path = forms.CharField(required=False)
```